# how to display multiple places in google maps having same latitude and longitude

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am using **Rails 4.0** with **gmaps4rails**. I am creating three addresses with same address, so longitude and latitude generated are same. In google maps only one marker displays although there are three addresses. How to display all these three addresses in google maps marker.

addresses_controller.rb

```
def index
  @addresses = Myaddress.all
  @json = @addresses.to_gmaps4rails
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'>
   <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Although i have three datas with same latitude and longitude in database, i want to display three markers in google maps.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have read video tutorial provided in the github for gmaps4rails v2. I have added underscore.js. Now i am facing following error:

```
 TypeError: Gmaps.build is not a function
 handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
```

users_controller.rb

```
 def index
   @users = User.all
   @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
   marker.lat user.latitude
   marker.lng user.longitude
end
```

end

index.html

```
   <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

   <div style='width: 800px;'>
     <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
   </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({
    provider: {
      disableDefaultUI: true
      // pass in other Google Maps API options here
    },
    internal: {
      id: 'map'
    }
  },
  function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  }
);
</script>
```

Comment: you should really use the v2 of the gem, there is a randomize option to handle such cases

Comment: @apneadiving: Map is not displaying due to the issue: TypeError: Gmaps.build is not a function

Comment: you have to use v2.x

Comment: @apneadiving: Yes i am using gmaps4rails (2.1.1)

Comment: then check your included js, I dont know your local issue http://apneadiving.github.io/

Comment: new issue i am facing: ReferenceError: google is not define point: google.maps.Point, in google/primitives.js line 5.  FYI i have tested http://apneadiving.github.io/ basic map, same issue.

Comment: do you include google maps js?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same question. Finally how did you handle the multiple points at the same location? Did you have any exemples of code with use of the randomize and maxRandomDistance possibilities?